# Can't connect with MySQL database, getting error "Fatal error: Class 'mysql_connect' not found in..."

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning the core [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) and write the below code for testing the connection with the database. I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'mysql_connect' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\index.php on line 4"

The code is below:

```
<?php
    $dbcon = new mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("demo", $dbcon);

    $query = mysql_query("select name FROM test ");
    echo mysql_num_row($query);
    mysql_close($dbcon);
?>
```

Comment: who has told you this "new mysql_connect" ? Basicly removing 'new' will solve your current problem, but mysql_ extension is not recommended to be used anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the below:

```
<?php
$dbcon = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); <-- remove "new"
mysql_select_db("demo", $dbcon);

$query = mysql_query("select name FROM test ");
echo mysql_num_row($query);
mysql_close($dbcon);
?>
```

Also, you should use PDO or MySQLi instead of mysql_* as it is now deprecated.

Comment: thanks scott, now getting this "Call to undefined function mysql_num_row() in .." error

Comment: It's mysql_num_rows() see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: You really should look to migrate to MySQLi or PDO, it's not too hard. Here is the equivalent MySQLi page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: @ChhatrapatiSharma Why you don't read the docs before asking?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot do `new mysql_connect`, `mysql_connect` is a **function** and **not** a Class.

---

Also [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 2):

mysql_connect is not a class, you should drop the "new". See the documentation: http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Also, mysql_ functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the 'new' keyword. That will be enough.